# Display a url in div when page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a url to load on a  of my page ? I tried several method but it doesn't work for me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#display").load("www.google.com");
});
</script>

<div id="display">
CONTENT SHOULD APPEAR HERE
</div>
```

This is a method that I got from w3cschool:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function go() {
    $('#display').html=("www.google.com");
}
$(document).ready(go);
</script>
```

Can anyone give me some idea how can I do it ? Thanks.

Comment: NO! you can't load external domains in your page this way. this is a cross domain policy issue, try reading about it.

Comment: do you need an iframe?

Comment: I love the use of the exclamation point here @Jai lol

Comment: You have to use Iframe for this but
Iframe will not work in case of google or facebook like web url because of security issues.

Comment: [About cross domain policy @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript#Cross-origin_network_access) try reading this.

Comment: [about cors to allow access cross domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comment. I learned something new today. I appreciate it a lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not gonna happen unless the page is on the same domain, protocol and subdomain as the one requesting it.

**From jQuery .load() API page:**

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Here is some reading material for you:

- [jQuery .load() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (wikipedia page)